# Pyqt5 multiple sizes tableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

[image]

i have created a window in qtDesigner where i have two frames, in frame1 there are two tableWidgets and frame2 i have one tableWidget. all tableWidget have same heights like 50-50%. i want to set the height of the frame1 or tableWidget1 &2 to  30% and frame2 will be 70% as shown in the image. may be it is easy to do or definitely have the functionality, but i am not able to find and do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>It is recommended that you provide an MRE, for example in your case it would be great if you provide the .ui, since you have not provided it then in my answer I will have to create it but it will not necessarily be the same as your samples.</sub>

---

As the QFrame are the containers of the QTableWidget then these define the height of them, and the size of them can be set through a QVBoxLayout they are a proportional stretching factor:

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout" stretch="3,7">
   <item>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget"/>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget_2"/>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget_3"/>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Great! worked. thanks for your help man . without your valuable help and support  it's difficult to make my project.